# type inference on empty arrays kotlin

Tags: kotlin, nullable

Let's say I have a piece of code like:

```
fun temp2 (li : MutableList<Int>):Int {
    if (li.isEmpty()) return 0
    val pos=li.filter { it>0 }
    val neg=li.filter { it<0 }

    if (pos.isEmpty() && neg.isNotEmpty()){

        // this gives compiling error because Required: Int, Found: Int?
        // But I just checked one line higher that neg is Not Empty, so there (at least I guess) 
       // no possible way to have an NPE?
        //return neg.max()
          return neg.max()!! //this works fine
    }
```

Is there any particular reason why compiler doesn't infer that .max() can only yield an Int, and thus this should not be an error, or am I missing something?
Kotlin's documentation proudly points out about Smart Casts, and I think this is a quite similar and easy inference to make?

Answer (score 4):

That can’t be handled by smart casting, you're using a `max()` extension function which always returns a nullable type, `Int?` in your case:

```
public fun <T : Comparable<T>> Iterable<T>.max(): T?
```

The compiler does what this method signature suggests: it makes you handle the possible `null`. How should the compiler know wether `max` works as intended? It might be implemented wrongly.

The following, on the other hand, works thanks to smart casting:

```
val maxNeg: Int? = li.filter { it < 0 }.max()
if (maxNeg != null) {
    return maxNeg //Can be used as Int
}
```

Comment: I understand it, but that's my point, there is no null possible :/

Comment: @dgan you’re right, it can’t be null. Have a look at the description of smart casting again and you will notice that the examples are different: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html

Comment: @dgan: the compiler can’t be sure that max works as intended. It simply sees the return type which might be null